# Android Pay Error

Tags: android, stripe-payments

IDK but i am continuously getting the error  **To make purchase using Android Pay, please setup your card in android pay app**

Even the card detail is added already in Android Pay App.And i am testing the app from US.

I followed up all the steps mentioned in the official site of Android pay with stripe i.e. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

Could you please help me out.

Any help will deeply appriciated. Please check the screenshots below.

[image: one]

Comment: Is it your application where it's happening? If so how do you sign it?

Comment: Yes, its my application where i integrated Android Pay. I am sign in using my own server, and for android pay i created project in google api console where i generated oAuth id for Google plus, the steps mentioned in Android pay tutorial site

Comment: hi mamta how you integrated android pay can you tell me

Comment: Yes, @Benjamin. I have implemented Android Pay in one of my app. You can take help from the link https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#add_a_purchase_button_and_request_the_masked_wallet. Or if there is any specific issue then please let me know

Comment: yes i added this but i am facing same issue like you

Comment: can you send your code to email

Comment: Hey Benjamin, you have a BOA card ?. If yes than some of the card are broken. Loose the BOA card, I couldn't get it to work either.
I use a Google wallet debit card.
I figured, if it wouldn't work with Google wallet, it wouldn't work with anything.
The problem with BOA seems to be one of card validation.
And your card definitely isn't validated.

So try to use different card details. So, on my android pay home page, I've got a Starbucks gift card, and a google wallet debit card.
what do you have?

Comment: after you click in button can you see any new card registration option in Android pay

Comment: Yes, If you don't have any card added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110992/discussion-between-benjamin-and-mamta-kaundal).

Comment: i doent see register your card .

Comment: is any problem i am registering card from india a US card

Comment: i am facing problem again \

Comment: same error   after start reworking on this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the fallowing conditions are met:

- Your package name is the package name in Developers console
- Your SH1 match the certificate you used to sign your app.
- The app version you are testing at is published in released or alpha in the Play store.
- You are **not** the owner of the app in play store - Owner account is not allowed to purchase

Comment: Is it compulsory to launch app in play store, to test Android Pay also?
Without launching the app in play store we can't test the Android pay ?

other than that i already use the same package name and SH1 certificates that i used in the app and SH1 that i get using cmd

Comment: @MamtaKaundal release it in alpha, that will do.

Comment: Okay.Thank you so much for the reply. I will do this and get back to you if issue still exist. :)

Comment: Hi @Ilya_Gazman can you give me a link of android pay integraion with step by step with stripe .